# Set up Git to CVS synchronisation

Tags: git, cvs

All my company's developer uses a CVS repository for all their source code. People recognize that there are better options available than CVS. They want to change now but still using both CVS and Git. So, is there anyway so that we can set up Git and CVS synchronisation in real time?